# BASH issue, counting variables in an array for FOR loop

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, for-loop, count

I'm having an issue with the following script. Due to my lack of knowledge of BASH, I am not 100% sure how to create a loop that uses "for" to count the amount of variables in an array and loop through each of them. Basically what I am wanting to do is having the script count up the amount of variables in variable $sqldumps, then run a MySQL Dump for each of them (also logging them into a database). The long version of the script is posted at the bottom, but here is a short version below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo -ne '\033]0;World of Clucky - Backup\007'
BINDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")"
cd "$BINDIR"
sqldumps=("lwc" "bans" "frisnuk_permissions" "jail" "imonies" "GriefP" "permissions" "showcase" "simpleclans")
#Copy MySQL Databases
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Starting MySQL Backup" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
for i in ${#sqldumps[*]}
    do
        echo "     ${sqldumps[i]}" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log;
        /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u'root' -p'CENSORED' --skip-lock-tables ${sqldumps[i]} > /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/MySQL/${sqldumps[i]}.sql;
    done
echo "     forum";
/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u'root' -p'CENSORED' forum >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/MySQL/forum.sql;
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] MySQL Backup Complete" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
```

The line in particular that I am having issues with is:

```
for i in ${#sqldumps[*]}
```

I am assuming that I am using the wrong syntax for this, so if anyone could give me the correct one, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo -ne '\033]0;World of Clucky - Backup\007'
BINDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")"
cd "$BINDIR"
timedate=`date '+%m.%d.%Y-%H:%M'`
sqldumps=("lwc" "bans" "frisnuk_permissions" "jail" "imonies" "GriefP" "permissions" "showcase" "simpleclans")
echo "-------------- `date '+%d-%B-%Y %H:%M'` --------------" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Starting Minecraft Backup" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
mkdir -p /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate
mkdir -p /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/MySQL
nice --adjustment=19 tar -zcpf /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/Minecraft.tar.gz \
    --directory /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/ \
    --exclude=SkyBlockkit \
    --exclude=Tekkit \
    --exclude=Vanilla \
    --exclude=test \
    --exclude=Zflocco_LP \
    --exclude=Mortuus/plugins/dynmap/web --exclude=Mortuus/plugins/AutoSaveWorld/backups --exclude Mortuus/CraftBukkitVersion --exclude=Mortuus/orebfuscator_cache --exclude=Mortuus/plugins/#Removed --exclude=Mortuus/server.log \
    --exclude=Frisnuk/plugins/dynmap/web --exclude=Frisnuk/plugins/AutoSaveWorld/backups --exclude Frisnuk/CraftBukkitVersion --exclude=Frisnuk/orebfuscator_cache --exclude=Frisnuk/plugins/#Removed --exclude=Frisnuk/plugins/#AwaitingUpdate --exclude=Frisnuk/server.log --exclude=Frisnuk/Suwako_Moriya100 --exclude=Frisnuk/Uk_Shadow --exclude=Frisnuk/Whiteghost99 --exclude=Frisnuk/greenrangermatt \
    --exclude=dailybackup.log \
    --exclude=.backups \
    --exclude=backup.log \
    --exclude=backups.log \
    --exclude=backupscript.sh \
    --exclude=dailybackup.sh \
    --exclude=.keptbackups .
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Minecraft Backup Complete" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
#Purge files 3 days old
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Purging Old Backups" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
find /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups* -mmin +4320 -exec rm --recursive {} \;
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Purging Complete" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
#Copy MySQL Databases
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Starting MySQL Backup" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
for i in ${#sqldumps[*]}
    do
        echo "     ${sqldumps[i]}" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log;
        /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u'root' -p'CENSORED' --skip-lock-tables ${sqldumps[i]} > /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/MySQL/${sqldumps[i]}.sql;
    done
echo "     forum";
/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u'root' -p'CENSORED' forum >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/MySQL/forum.sql;
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] MySQL Backup Complete" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
echo "[`date '+%H:%M'`] Daily Backup Complete" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
#Read back file size
filesize=$(ls -lah /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate | awk '{ print $5}')
echo "     Total Compression Size: $filesize\n" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Do you need to know the number of variables in the array or could you just use the array "map" method?

Comment: Truely, i really dont know. I just need a way for the script to loop through all of the variables in the array $sqldumps and run a MySQL dump for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `${#varname[*]}` returns the size of the array, but the `for` syntax you use wants to be given a list of elements. So, either you want:

```
for elem in "${varname[@]}"; do
    ... something with ${elem} ...
done
```

or

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#varname[@]}; i++ )); do
    ... something with ${varname[$i]} ...
done
```

Note, I use `@` instead of `*` as that's generally a good prophylactic against elements that contain spaces (even though it may not strictly be necessary in this case).

Comment: WORKED GREAT! THANKS! I tried the second one, and it worked exactly as I needed it to. Also, thanks for the tip about the `*` and `@` as I was wondering what the difference was. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't index over the array, just use the values:

```
for value in "${sqldumps[@]}"; do echo $value; done
```

Comment: I do need the variable `i` to increment by 1 each time though, right? so how would I specify this?

Comment: @JesseAaronBellas: With this form, you don't need `i` at all. The only thing you needed it for was to fetch the `i`'th element of the array, and this form gives you the elements directly. Just replace `${sqldumps[i]}` with `$value` inside the loop, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of reorganizing your script a bit to make it more readable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Script starts here.
main() {
    backup_dir=~clucky/MinecraftServers
    dbs=(lwc bans frisnuk_permissions jail imonies GriefP permissions showcase simpleclans forum)

    echo -ne '\033]0;World of Clucky - Backup\007'

    log 'Starting MySQL Backup'
    dump_dbs "${dbs[@]}"
    log 'MySQL Backup Complete'
}

# Write a timestamped message to the log file.
log() {
    echo "[$(date '+%H:%M')] $*" >> "$backup_dir/backup.log"
}

# Dump each of the databases passed as an argument. The list of databases is "$@".
dump_dbs() {
    for db in "$@"; do
        # Use --skip-lock-tables for every database except "forum".
        local options=(--skip-lock-tables)
        [[ $db = forum ]] && options=()

        log "     $db"
        /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root -p CENSORED "${options[@]}" "$db" \
            > "$backup_dir/.backups/$timedate/MySQL/$db.sql"
    done
}

main "$@"
```

Here are some of the things I did:

1. Rather than iterating over the array indices, a loop like this will iterate over each value directly:

   ```
   for value in "${array[@]}"; do ...; done
   ```
2. It's shorter to use `~user` to refer to a user's home directory. It's also safer as users' home directories aren't necessarily under `/home`.
3. Breaking up the code into separate functions helps eliminate some of the redundancies such as writing the full path to `backup.log` repeatedly. The log() function puts the timestamped message line in one place.
4. The `forum` table doesn't get the `--skip-lock-tables` option so I made that more explicit which made it possible to get rid of the duplicate `mysqldump` line.
5. I removed quotes from places they weren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

`$i` will hold each item in an array incrementing itself until it reaches the end. So you don't have to reference the array each time you need it within the `for` loop. I also, don't like to hard code `echo`, this is a personal preference, so I swapped it out with `printf`.

```
for i in ${#sqldumps[@]}
  do
    printf "     %s" "$i" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/backup.log;
    /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u'root' -p'CENSORED' --skip-lock-tables $i > /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/.backups/$timedate/MySQL/${sqldumps[i]}.sql;
done
```

If you would just like to find the size of an array you could use.

```
Length=${#sqldumps[@]}
```

And `$Length` would then equal the number of places in the array